# Scroll-able table while header is always on top with correct alignment

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have create a Table containing 3 headers the functionality should be the header will stay on top while the contents/data will be scroll-able below since it will be populated by the server my problem lies on the alignment on the header and corresponding data. since i'am using a Display: inline-block or block the header and the data don't align together i have tried to do it manually by adding some padding's but another problem lies within the responsiveness of the headers when i resize the view port the changes don't align correctly. Below is the example of the code that i am working

**Jsfiddle Link**: https://jsfiddle.net/pynechan/5bxm9n0p/

```css
table {
  width:100%
}

tbody {
    border:1px solid red;
    height:300px;
    overflow:auto;
    display:inline-block;
}

thead {
    background-color:#0c0;
    color:#fff;

}
```

```html
<h2>Header fixed</h2>
<br/>
<br/>

<table>
    <thead><tr><th>HEADER</th><th>HEADER 2</th><th>HEADER 3</th></tr></thead>
  
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: if you are using `display:inline-block` in `tbody`...its not a  table anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the below one. The header will be static while the table contents scroll keeping the header in a static way.

```css
 table {
    max-width:980px;
    table-layout:fixed;
    margin:auto;
}
th, td {
    padding:5px 10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
thead, tfoot {
    background:#f9f9f9;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    width:calc(100% - 18px);
}
tbody {
    height:300px;
    overflow:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
tbody tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

```html
        <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Header 1</th>
      <th scope="col">Header 2</th>
      <th scope="col">Header 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `display` property in `tbody` fixes the issue.

```
tbody {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I came up with

```css
table {
  width:100%
}

tbody {
    border:1px solid red;
    height:300px;
    overflow:auto;
    display:block;
}

thead {
    background-color:#0c0;
    color:#fff;
    display: block;

}
```

```html
<h2>Header fixed</h2>
<br/>
<br/>

<table>
    <thead><tr><th>HEADER</th><th>HEADER 2</th><th>HEADER 3</th></tr></thead>
  
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1. DATA</td><td>1. DATA 2</td><td>1. DATA 3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help sir :)

Answer (score 0):

```
To scroll tbody, change it to block level element i.e. display:block;

To keep behavior of table, change it to table i.e. display: table;

Finally use table-layout:fixed to spray evenly the cells

Here is what i changed:

tbody {
    display:block;
    max-height:160px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
thead, tbody tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```